# Dynamic Reactive Angular form unable to scroll to top

Tags: angular

I have a form that can be large in size.

both `Window.scrollTo(0,0);` and `this.viewportScroller.scrollToPosition([0, 0]);` can scroll to the top. However they all scroll to the top before the page has rendered.

If I place the scroll into `ngAfterViewChecked()`
The page will continue to scroll to the top every time I scroll down the page.

If I place it into `ngAfterViewInit()`
It calls the method too early
[image]

If I place it in `ngAfterContentChecked()`
it does the same as ngAfterViewChecked and keeps me at the top of the page even while trying to scroll down.

If I place it in `ngAfterContentInit()`
It again calls it too early

Any ideas - the content is dynamic in length. I generate a dynamic number of div's with large content.

Comment: How and where are you generating the dynamic content? I am assuming there is an api call, and on the response you are generating the content. Possible solution is to trigger the change detection to update the UI and after that scroll to top.

Comment: hi @j4rey yes - API call. how would I go about doing that?

Comment: First change your `ChangeDetectionStrategy` to `OnPush` and you would have to inject `ChangeDetectorRef` and call `detectChanges()` to trigger the change detection and update the UI. https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

Comment: ok, and if I do all that where do I place my scrollto method? Also, if I change data on the form will it trigger the scroll again?

Comment: that depends on you based on, assuming if you put all the code inside the http subscribe, then every time the api is called, it will update the ui and scroll to top.